# Why can I dynamically call an inherited class public method, but not a protected one?

Tags: abap

The question is complex, so it is easier to explain to you with an example:

Consider the following `ZCL_FOO` class:

```
CLASS zcl_foo DEFINITION
  PUBLIC
  CREATE PUBLIC .

  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS: bar
      RETURNING VALUE(return) TYPE string,
      constructor.
  PROTECTED SECTION.
    DATA: mv_dynamic_method TYPE string.
    METHODS: protected_bar.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS zcl_foo IMPLEMENTATION.

  METHOD constructor.
    mv_dynamic_method = 'PROTECTED_BAR'.
  ENDMETHOD.


  METHOD bar.
    CALL METHOD (mv_dynamic_method).

    return = mv_dynamic_method.
  ENDMETHOD.


  METHOD protected_bar.
    WRITE 'protected_bar'.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

And the following `ZCL_QUX` class, which inherits from `ZCL_FOO`:

```
CLASS zcl_qux DEFINITION
  PUBLIC
  FINAL
  CREATE PUBLIC
  INHERITING FROM zcl_foo .

  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS constructor.
  PROTECTED SECTION.
    METHODS xyz.
  PRIVATE SECTION.

ENDCLASS.



CLASS ZCL_QUX IMPLEMENTATION.


  METHOD xyz.
    WRITE 'XYZ'.
  ENDMETHOD.


  METHOD constructor.
    super->constructor( ).
    mv_dynamic_method = 'XYZ'.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

Note that `xyz` is **PROTECTED**.

If I execute `qux->bar( )`, for example by running it through SE24, I receive a short dump: `CX_SY_DYN_CALL_ILLEGAL_METHOD`.

However, if I move `xyz` from PROTECTED to **PUBLIC**, I am able to run `qux->bar( )` successfully.

I tried to change the bar method to use `CALL METHOD me->(mv_dynamic_method).`, but it also short dumps.

Is that an ABAP bug or intended feature? In my opinion, it should not short dump.

Comment: xyz is a protected method in child class so the parent class cannot access the method.

Comment: @Haojie: But then, in theory, how can the parent access a child-only public method?

Comment: Although technically possible, a parent class should never access the members of a child class. It's an important design principle. Explain what is your final goal, and we'll tell you how to do it.

Comment: `But then, in theory, how can the parent access a child-only public method?` it's because public methods of public classes can be called by anybody, not only by parents, so `zcl_foo` calls it just like any alien class. Calling parent-child methods dynamically like this create unnecessary recursion so your task looks pretty unnatural and artificial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intentional and follows object-oriented design.

`PROTECTED` is a one-way route: you can use it to make parents' attributes visible in children, but not the other way around. Your example tries exactly that forbidden opposite direction.

More precisely, any class will only ever be able to access own methods that were either defined in itself, or inherited as public or protected from its super class. `xyz` is neither defined in `zcl_foo`, nor in a super class, so `zcl_foo` cannot see it.

Unfortunately, your example doesn't really explain why you need that dynamic call. The typical pattern in object orientation would be that `zcl_foo` declares `xyz` as `protected`, and `zcl_qux` overrides that method.

What you *could* do, is this:

```
CLASS parent DEFINITION PUBLIC CREATE PUBLIC.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS call_sub.
  PROTECTED SECTION.
    DATA method_name TYPE string.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS parent IMPLEMENTATION.

  METHOD call_sub.
    CALL METHOD (method_name).
  ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.
```

Then override `call_sub` in each sub-class:

```
CLASS child DEFINITION PUBLIC CREATE PUBLIC
    INHERITING FROM zcl_fh_so_parent.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS constructor.
    METHODS call_sub REDEFINITION.
  PROTECTED SECTION.
    METHODS call_me.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS child IMPLEMENTATION.

  METHOD constructor.
    super->constructor( ).
    method_name = `CALL_ME`.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD call_sub.
    CALL METHOD (method_name).
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD call_me.
    DATA(success) = 'Hooray!'.
  ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.
```

But that pattern doesn't really make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the fun, here is the incorrect way to do what you ask, but anybody will tell you **DON'T EVER DO THAT, IT'S A VERY BAD DESIGN, WHICH MAY LEAD TO MANY UNDERLYING PROBLEMS !**

```
CLASS zcl_foo DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS:
      constructor,
      bar
        RETURNING VALUE(return) TYPE string.
  PROTECTED SECTION.
    DATA: mv_dynamic_method TYPE string.
    METHODS: protected_bar.
ENDCLASS.
CLASS zcl_qux DEFINITION
    INHERITING FROM zcl_foo
    FRIENDS zcl_foo. " <==== so that ZCL_FOO may use private/protected members of ZCL_QUX
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS constructor.
  PROTECTED SECTION.
    METHODS xyz.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS zcl_foo IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD constructor.
    mv_dynamic_method = 'PROTECTED_BAR'.
  ENDMETHOD.
  METHOD bar.
    DATA(cast) = CAST object( me ).        " <=========== Cast needed
    CALL METHOD cast->(mv_dynamic_method). " <=========== Cast needed
    return = mv_dynamic_method.
  ENDMETHOD.
  METHOD protected_bar.
    WRITE 'protected_bar'.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS zcl_qux IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD xyz.
    WRITE 'XYZ'.
  ENDMETHOD.
  METHOD constructor.
    super->constructor( ).
    mv_dynamic_method = 'XYZ'.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  DATA(qux) = NEW zcl_qux( ).
  qux->bar( ).
```